# Is AB the equivalent of A^B?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, algebra, boolean-algebra

Doing some boolean algebra. I am under the assumption that `AB(B+~C)` can also be written as

```
A^B ^ (B+~C) OR (A AND B)AND(B OR ~C)
```

Is this true?

If that is the case then for the following expression I simplified that if

```
A=1 B=1 C=0  

A^B(B^~C) 
= (1^1) ^ (1 OR 1) 
= 1 ^ 1
= 1
= True`
```

Does this make sense or does 
    AB 
mean something else entirely?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. `AB` and `A∧B` are equivalent. And

```
A | B | C | A∧B | B∨¬C | (A∧B)∧(B∨¬C)
-------------------------------------
0 | 0 | 0 |  0  |  1   |      0
0 | 0 | 1 |  0  |  0   |      0
0 | 1 | 0 |  0  |  1   |      0
0 | 1 | 1 |  0  |  1   |      0
1 | 0 | 0 |  0  |  1   |      0
1 | 0 | 1 |  0  |  0   |      0
1 | 1 | 0 |  1  |  1   |      1
1 | 1 | 1 |  1  |  1   |      1
```